# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value using JSON file and SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

I have this code in swift in the `parseJSON()` function it will retrieve the `Makes` in the json file but I got an error said `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

**NOTE:** I'm using SwiftyJSON and the error is pointing in the `if condition`

```
func parseJSON() {

            let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("vehicles", ofType: "json") as String!
            let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!
            let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
            numberOfRows = readableJSON.count
            for element in 1...numberOfRows {
                var Makes = readableJSON[element]["Make"]

                if !makeArray.contains(Makes.string! && ){ // error is pointing here!
                    let Make = readableJSON[element]["Make"].string as String!
                    makeArray.append(Make)
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: @EricD. can you please show me how to do the "if let statement" i tried it but it will have an error. thanks

Comment: Ok, I'm writing an answer.

Comment: ... and the proper `force unwrap` syntax is `as! Type` rather than `as Type!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.string` property of a SwiftyJSON object is an *optional getter*.

Its value can exist or be nil.

So you have to *safely* unwrap it before using it.

The simplest example:

```
if let makeString = Makes.string {
    if !makeArray.contains(makeString) {
        let Make = readableJSON[element]["Make"].stringValue
        makeArray.append(Make)
    }
}
```

As you can note, with SwiftyJSON, the opposite of the optional `.string` getter is the non-optional `.stringValue` getter.

But beware! If this property is nil, the app will crash.

`.stringValue` is the same as `.string!`

So you could also use the optional getter and "if let" there too:

```
if let makeString = Makes.string {
    if !makeArray.contains(makeString) {
        if let Make = readableJSON[element]["Make"].string {
            makeArray.append(Make)
        } else {
            // readableJSON[element]["Make"].string is nil, handle the error
        }
    }
} else {
    // Makes.string is nil, handle the error
}
```

etc, you get the idea.

It can also be simplified like this by using `where`:

```
if let makeString = Makes.string where !makeArray.contains(makeString) {
    if let Make = readableJSON[element]["Make"].string {
        makeArray.append(Make)
    } else {
        // readableJSON[element]["Make"].string is nil, handle the error
    }
} else {
    // Either Makes.string is nil or makeArray does contain it, handle the rror
}
```